# CSS Toggable tab change dynamically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the background color for a ratio label button using JavaScript to change it dynamically once the user clicks on a specific button.

If you look at the underneath link, once you click on the blue or red box the yellow bar and text change but I also want the [type=radio]:checked ~ label button to change.

http://jsfiddle.net/thepaddyman/XWjJm/

```
$("document").ready(function(){

        $(".red").click(function(){
        $(".content").css("border-top-color","red");   
        $(".content").css("color","red"); }); }); 



        $("document").ready(function(){
        $(".blue").click(function(){
        $(".content").css("border-top-color","blue");     
        $(".content").css("color","blue"); 

}); });
```

Thanks a million

Patrick

Comment: You don't need the nested `$(document).ready()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/XWjJm/2/)

You don't need to have nested `$(document).ready()` as hjpotter92 suggested

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".red,#tab-1").click(function () {
        $(".content").css("border-top-color", "red");
        $(".content").css("color", "red");
    });
    $(".blue,#tab-2").click(function () {
        $(".content").css("border-top-color", "blue");
        $(".content").css("color", "blue");
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers guys but I want to be able to change the actual tab color it self. Example If you click on the blue square all the content will turn blue, If you click on the red square all the content will turn red. Including the tab

Comment: For example I was trying $("[type=radio]:checked ~ label ").css("background-color","blue");

Comment: see updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/XWjJm/3/ .. now you can easily play around this to achieve what you want

Comment: If you view my portfolio site in progress at http://patrickhdoorly.com/sample/index-tabs.html then click on projects and change the color with the side nav you can see the effect I am trying to achieve. Do you think it is possible to change the tabs background color. Thanks Patrick

Comment: I decided to use a different toggle tab